# How to call OnDateChangedListener in DatePickerDialog using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using DatePickerDialog. I am able to use it well but what I want is that i don't want to click "OK" button after setting date. I want that as soon as date changes dialog should dismiss. How do I do this? On Stack Overflow, questions that I found are related to `DatePicker`, but not to `DatePickerDialog`.

```
 val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(this@MainActivity,
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
                    try {
                        // do something with date
                    } catch (e: Exception) { }
                }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
     datePickerDialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to take out datePickerDialog, like in MainActivity add field `private lateinit var datePickerDialog: DatePickerDialog` and below

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(this@MainActivity,
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
                    try {
                        // do something with date
                    } catch (e: Exception) { }
                    datePickerDialog.dismiss()
                }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
     datePickerDialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

A psuedocode i am currently using and its working for me now.So anyone who need a quick solution can use this until someone posts actual answer

```
 val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(this@MainActivity,
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
                    try {
                       //do something
                    } catch (e: Exception) { }
                }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
/* instead of above code u can also use 
val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(this@MainActivity)
*/
        
        val datepicker = datePickerDialog.datePicker
        datepicker.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
            try {
                //do something
            } catch (e: Exception) { }
        }
        datePickerDialog.show()
```